# How to open or invoke the regexTester plugin in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I am comparatively new to Intellij IDEA(community edition) plugin.

I just installed [this](http://myregexp.com/ideaPlugin.html)

Plugin for testing and verifying the regex in Intellij, but I am not able to invoke the plugin window from anywhere.

I tried going to *Settings > Plugins* but no luck.

Anybody has an idea about using this plugin on intelliJ?

Comment: You could always try `Ctrl + Shift + A` and typing `Regex Tester` or just `Regex`. It will also show you a shortcut, if there is one assigned.

Comment: Thanks it worked. You could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always try `Ctrl + Shift + A` and typing `Regex Tester` or just `Regex`. It will also show you a shortcut, if there is one assigned.

Answer (score 6):

In Intellij 1.5.06 (I guess that this is relevant to newer versions as well).

1. Make sure it's installed and enabled (Restart Intellij if needed)
   File->Setting->Search Plugins->Search RegexTester
2. Got to the icon on the lower left corner click and select RegexTester

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ, the RegEx plugin tester is available as an intention within source code.  The intention should automatically appear when the cursor is within the regular expression pattern string.  If the intention doesn't, try `Alt + Enter` when cursor is within regular expression.

There are two main reasons why the intention does not appear:

1. The Check RegExp Intention is disabled.  Verify using `Ctrl + Shift + A` and enter text `Check RegExp`.
2. The IntelliLang plugin is disabled.  Verify using 'Ctrl + Shift + A' and enter `IntelliLang`.   *(In 2018.2 regular expression support is bundled within this plugin.)*

Hope this helps you/others.